# How can I detect reference loops in an EF-generated many-to-many self-reference relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I have a collection of objects like the example `Foo` below:

```
public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> FooParents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> FooChildren { get; set; }
}
```

These objects are related to each other by the properties `FooParents` and `FooChildren`.

How can I effectively detect a circular dependency for a specific `Foo`?

I know, what to do in case of one-to-many, but in case of many-to-many, I am a little bit confused.

:(

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Please show us the `CREATE TABLE` statements of the tables and other objects that EF created for you. Are you using EF migrations at all?

Comment: What does `Foo` represent, exactly? Could you use a Graph Table instead?

Comment: Presumably you want to expand all the hierarchies so you get a string for each branch of the family tree, breaking with an exception as soon as a `Foo.Id` repeats in a string. You can optimise by storing a lookup of strings by `Id` as you build.

Comment: Its only necessary to store one of the "Pigs Ear" relationships in  the data, as one can be derived from the other.

Comment: *I am a little bit confused* -- Could you be more specific? I don't see how circular references in 1:n are fundamentally different from m:n. Also, this looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to detect these circular references?

Comment: Seeing all the above comments. This question is lacking (debugging) details about the actual underlying problem. It's a pity stack overflow doesn't allow for close votes when there's a bounty on a question (which is dumb imho)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is an implementation with some tests](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sUaHiP).

This is a generic solution that performs a [**D**epth-**F**irst **S**earch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)
with behaviour specialised to your problem domain. It keeps a history of visited nodes in the `soFar` hash set, completing when either a duplicate is encountered or the paths along the specified branches are exhausted.

A duplicate indicates a circular relationship.

This extension method must be supplied with a number delegates. First a key selector that yields a unique identifier for each item. Then any number of axis selectors that represent the branches, upon which, the object graph extends.

The interesting extension method is here,

```
public static bool IsCircular<T, K>(
    this T item,
    Func<T, K> keySelector, 
    params Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>[] axes)
{
    var soFar = new HashSet<K>();
    soFar.Add(keySelector(item));
    return axes.Any(axis =>
        axis(item).Any(next => IsCircularOnAxis(
            next,
            keySelector,
            axis,
            soFar)));
}

private static bool IsCircularOnAxis<T, K>(
    T item,
    Func<T, K> keySelector,
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> axisSelector, 
    HashSet<K> soFar)
{
    var key = keySelector(item);
    if(soFar.Contains(key))
    {
        return true;
    }

    soFar.Add(key);
    return axisSelector(item).Any(next => 
        IsCircularOnAxis(
            next,
            keySelector,
            axisSelector,
            soFar));
}
```

In this case of `Foo`, the extension method would be called like this,

```
someFoo.IsCircular(
    foo => foo.Id,           /*The key selector*/
    foo => foo.FooParents,   /*The parent axis selector*/
    foo => foo.FooChildren); /*The child axis selector*/
```

The full working example is here, with some tests for `Foo`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var soloFoo = new Foo
        {
            Id = 1,
            FooParents = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
            FooChildren = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
        };
        Console.WriteLine($"soloFoo isCircular:{soloFoo.IsCircular(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo.FooParents, foo => foo.FooChildren)}");
        
        var selfParent = new Foo
        {
            Id = 1,
            FooChildren = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
        };
        selfParent.FooParents = new[] { selfParent };
        Console.WriteLine($"selfParent isCircular:{selfParent.IsCircular(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo.FooParents, foo => foo.FooChildren)}");
        
        
        var selfChild = new Foo
        {
            Id = 1,
            FooParents = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
        };
        selfChild.FooChildren = new[] { selfChild };
        Console.WriteLine($"selfChild isCircular:{selfChild.IsCircular(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo.FooParents, foo => foo.FooChildren)}");
        
        var parentFoo = new Foo
        {
            Id = 1,
            FooParents = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
            FooChildren = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
        };
        var childFoo = new Foo
        {
            Id = 2,
            FooParents = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
            FooChildren = Enumerable.Empty<Foo>(),
        };
        var middleFoo = new Foo
        {
            Id = 3,
            FooParents = new[] { parentFoo },
            FooChildren = new[] { childFoo },
        };
        Console.WriteLine($"middleFoo isCircular:{middleFoo.IsCircular(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo.FooParents, foo => foo.FooChildren)}");
        
        var ringFooA = new Foo
        {
            Id = 1,
        };
        var ringFooB = new Foo
        {
            Id = 2,
            FooParents = new[] { ringFooA },
        };
        var ringFooC = new Foo
        {
            Id = 3,
            FooParents = new[] { ringFooB },
            FooChildren = new[] { ringFooA },
        };
        ringFooA.FooParents = new[] { ringFooC };
        ringFooA.FooChildren = new[] { ringFooB };
        ringFooB.FooChildren = new[] { ringFooC };
        Console.WriteLine($"ringFooA isCircular:{ringFooA.IsCircular(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo.FooParents, foo => foo.FooChildren)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"ringFooB isCircular:{ringFooB.IsCircular(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo.FooParents, foo => foo.FooChildren)}");
        Console.WriteLine($"ringFooC isCircular:{ringFooC.IsCircular(foo => foo.Id, foo => foo.FooParents, foo => foo.FooChildren)}");
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsCircular<T, K>(
        this T item,
        Func<T, K> keySelector, 
        params Func<T, IEnumerable<T>>[] axes)
    {
        var soFar = new HashSet<K>();
        soFar.Add(keySelector(item));
        return axes.Any(axis =>
            axis(item).Any(next => IsCircularOnAxis(
                next,
                keySelector,
                axis,
                soFar)));
    }

    private static bool IsCircularOnAxis<T, K>(
        T item,
        Func<T, K> keySelector,
        Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> axisSelector, 
        HashSet<K> soFar)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        if(soFar.Contains(key))
        {
            return true;
        }

        soFar.Add(key);
        return axisSelector(item).Any(next => 
            IsCircularOnAxis(
                next,
                keySelector,
                axisSelector,
                soFar));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> FooParents { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Foo> FooChildren { get; set; }
}
```